# Remove column header on SharePoint 2007 list webpart in Team Site

Tags: web-part, list

I have a list on a Team Site-based (customised site definition) site collection. I want display its contents on the front page of the site in a web part with the list title and one field only in the detail display (in a boxed view) but remove the column header. There doesn't seem to be an option to do this in the edit web part dialogue. Is there some way to get rid of the column headers other than making a custom list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataViewWebPart?

jQuery would work too.

Comment: Full display control with the DVWP.  I'd go that way.

Comment: Yup DVWP, easy peasy!  Cannot believe Marc is recommending DVWP or JQuery ;-)

Comment: You and your wry wit.  DVWPs can move mountains.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a custom site definition do you have access to the schema.xml file for the list? It is easy to create a different view that does exactly what you want and then you can use the view on your page.

Another option is to use javascript or jQuery to hide it.

Comment: Yes, we have done that with our custom lists that form part of the site definition but this is a standard list and web part that someone has added to the site later so we don't have access to the schema.